# Solving $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}sin(x^2)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Solve: $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin(x^2)}{x}$$

Note: $[x]$ is the floor function ( the greatest integer function) . So, usually $(-1)^n$ is bounded between $1$ and $-1$, $[x]$ is bounded $x-1<[x]\le x$ and also $|\sin x^2|\le 1$ . The problem is with $(-1)^{[x]}$ which i am not sure how to evaluate... I am thinking that the answer might be $0$ .

Comment: Hint : $|\sin(u)|\leq |u|$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you have

$$0 \le \left|\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin(x^2)}{x}\right| = \left|x\left(\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\right)\right| \le |x| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This uses the hint in [Kelenner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/159886/kelenner)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585226/solving-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-1xsinx2x/3585234#comment7370862_3585226) that $|\sin(u)| \le |u|$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$ (e.g., see [Proof that sin(x) ≤ x for All Positive Real Numbers](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers)). Thus, you have that as $x \to 0$, the right side of \eqref{eq1A} goes to $0$, so by the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem),

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin(x^2)}{x} = 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $-1\leq(-1)^{[x]}\leq1$, by squeeze theorem we know either

$$-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin x^2}{x}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}$$

or

$$-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}\geq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin x^2}{x}\geq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}$$

(this depends on the sign of $\frac{\sin x^2}{x}$). We can evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}$ by l'Hopital's rule: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x\cos x^2}1$$

Simplifying further, we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x\cos x^2}1=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}2x\cos x^2=2\cdot0\cdot\cos0^2=2\cdot0\cdot1=0$$

Plugging this back in, we have

$$-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin x^2}{x}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x^2}{x}\Rightarrow-0\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin x^2}{x}\leq0$$

And by squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(-1)^{[x]}\sin x^2}{x}=0$.

Comment: Some of your inequalities are reversed when $x$ is negative.  But this is the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

$$RL=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{(-1)^{[x]} \sin x^2}{x} =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(-1)^{[h]} \sin h^2}{h}\frac{h}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(-1)^{[h]} \sin h^2}{h^2} h=0$$
Simolarly,
$$LL+-=L=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{(-1)^{[x]} \sin x^2}{x} =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(-1)^{[-h]} \sin h^2}{-h}\frac{h}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(-1)^{[h]} \sin h^2}{h^2} (-h)=0$$
Both the left and the riight limit being finite and equal the required limit exists and it is 0.